# Why India is only country favouring Hinduism?

Tags: vishnu, gods

Why India is only country favouring Hinduism?

If our god has created all universe and world, they must be recognise across the world and shows his supernatural power at very corner of other part where injustices happen.

Why ISIS growing his terrorist activities? Lord must stop it all.

Comment: That's long history. We live in Kali Yuga and Dharma decreases with everyday. Yeah, there is only one GOD. Indeed the sufferings and bad things across the world are results of many past actions. When injustice reaches pinnacle, Lord incarnates on earth. We cannot term other religions as false. Jesus is realized soul and some say Allah is Shiva or Shakti. So, we need to remove misapprehensions and misinterpretations in religions. Every human experiences fruits (whether good or bad) based on his Karma. ISIS are deluded Jivas and let them face their Karma.

Comment: Initially Sanatana Dharma (Eternal Righteousness) as way of life was followed in whole world but by beginning of Kali Yuga (age of vice), Sanatana Dharma as Hinduism is limited to Indian subcontinent and later to India. Many religions sprouted in west. However, God is one. Some people in India claim that Kalki (avatar of Lord Vishnu) will fight against ISIS during world war 3. We can't really know whether Lord will incarnate or not. All we need to do is to meditate on Him and ask Him.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... It means we all are helpless now... God have to save us from all bad things.  God has to unite us all under one roof.   But why all happens in old ancient era. Why not now God take birth and help mind kind.

Comment: Not necessarily. We must always put our efforts to stop evil but we must have blessings of Lord to stop evil smoothly.  Actually, Lord won't interfere in day to day tasks unless His devotees ask Him. He gives us freedom and we, the deluded souls, make the world filthy. When evil reaches pinnacle, Lord will come to earth to remove this filth and establish Dharma (Righteousness). Actually, there nothing called Supernatural or magic. All these acts of so called supernatural things or magics can be explained by Vedic Science.

Comment: I read somewhere Brahmins came from European nations to India. They were white and powerful. They brought Hinduism with them.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism_by_country

Actually there are very few countries with a significant number of Hindus.

> By total number, India has the most Hindus. By percentage, Nepal has the largest majority of Hindu population in the world followed by India and Mauritius.

Since over 95% of all Hindus are in India, it looks like there is only one country where Hinduism is dominant.

> Why ISIS growing his terrorist activities? Lord must stop it all.

This seems off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Why there is no Hindu Avatar story outside India? Why all carriers of Avatars are animals found in India only?

Thats because the concepts native to Hinduism originated in India. Hinduism is full of philosophical concepts and Mythology. Vedas teach worship of devatas (Indra, Agni, varuna etc) and some philosophy is found in it which is known as Monism. Then during upanishadic period this developed in to Monistic Idealism or Idealistic Monism. Then came the period of Mythology (Puranas and Itihasas). Thus all these developments are Indian thought and native to this land.

So Obviously Hinduism is favored in India.

Comment: There are Avatars outside India. Varaha Avatar lifts the earth (you may understand this with allegory). Kurma Avatar didn't happen on Earth. There are still many unidentified places in Puranas. They might present outside Indian Subcontinent. Sruti (the one which are recounted orally) has no origin. They are the words of BRAHMAN.

Comment: Lifting earth out of water? You see all that is myth, the question is why there is no mention of that Avatar in other scriptures outside India.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Lifting earth out of water? You see all that is myth, the question is why there is no mention of that Avatar in other scriptures outside India.

Comment: [Mythology has two meanings](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/293/3500). In reality all stories of Puranas are history and indeed Purana means history in Sanskrit. Some people interpret metaphorically and some believe these stories literally happened. My point is you are mistaken, there are indeed stories outside India. These stories are not creations of Humans.

Comment: @TheDestroyer .. Please give me one reference of Indian Avatar mentioned in scriptures outside India.

Comment: @TheDestroyer  ..  In Siva Purana, Siva has been described as Lord of all; Usha, Brahman, Ganesh, Indra and Surya are spoken as servants. Vishnu Purana holds Vishnu on highest pedestal and Shiva and other Gods as servants. For Devi Purana , Devi is Supreme and others totally subordinate; In this way, Shiva Purana describes Siva; Vishnu Purana, Vishnu ; Devi Purana, Devi; Ganesh Purana, Ganesh; Surya, Surya; Vayu, Vayu; etc as author of creation and destruction of universe, but each of them consider the other as created ones... Dr. RK Lahri.

Comment: @TheDestroyer  Its clear that Puranas are works of human beings.

Comment: I told you already, Varaha is for entire earth and Kurma happened in spiritual world where only your Subtle body ( Subtle body is real and i'm making up things here) can go there. Regarding your confusion, there are already reasons for that. In different [Kalpas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(aeon)), Supreme God created others through each of them consecutively. So, in Kalpa, Supreme created others via Vishnu and in other Kalpa via Shiva, according to Shiva Purana. So, Indeed this again shows God is one and all Devas are different aspects of him.

Comment: No other faith ever said about vast nature of cosmos and large timescales such as [Kalpas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(aeon)), Vikalpa and cyclic nature of time which is very close to Modern Science.  By the way, you should under more about Subtle body and other stuff to understand how Hanuman was able to fly and every other aspect of Sanatana Dharma. So, these are not creations of Humans and indeed we consider body as cosmos and Man is microcosm. Indeed, it is very difficult to explain Hindu Philosophy in one comment.

Comment: But this doesn't mean only Hinduism is true Religion. All Religions are true and they are different paths to reach one GOD. This is all play or sport of GOD (leela).

Comment: @TheDestroyer - I think you are not getting the point here., I am asking if these stories about Avatars are correct, why there are no references or recordings of these in other scriptures in other parts of the world. You are saying have answered without answering, please understand the question first.

Comment: @TheDestroyer - "Cyclic nature of time"  - what do you mean by that? Is there a scientific evidence that time is cyclic in nature? Or how can we know that rationally?

Comment: @TheDestroyer  God created others through each of them consecutively. Can you please provide evidence for this concept from scriptures?  Its not enough to come out with explanations out of thin air to explain contradictions., please back up with evidence.  If vishnu, shiva etc are only devatas and that God is different , why are we not worshipping that God and worshipping the devatas?

Comment: See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2712/3500). Should i mention all places that are not identified? Matsya happened during floods and there is similar stories in other mythology. This Matsya happened outside India or probably world was different at those times. I'm not making any things here. See [this Answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11077/3500). Previous chapter too describes the same and it says Rudra, Vishnu and Brahma are same no one should censure or demean others.

Comment: I said i can't explain all Philosophy in one comment.  Initially a devotee worships his/her Ista Deva (which is aspect of Supreme Brahman). Later if devotion increases He sees all Gods as one and forgets all negative traits and treat all Gods and even Humans as equal.Then He his worship reaches supreme Lord. Hinduism has many schools and you should know a lot of stuff to understand it. Many people worship God or Devas for materialistic desires. But a person with true knowledge aim for Moksha where he won't take birth again and mingle with eternal all pervading auspicious consciousness.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I understand the different streams in Hinduism.  I notice that to explain inconsistencies or contradictions you use your own notions without any scriptural evidence and sometimes distort facts.. for example, its mentioned - "Islam also considers shiva as god, in mecca there is a shiva lingam whom they call Noor-e-ilahi, noor means light, we call the same jyoti, and ilahi means god, Jyotirlingam or noor -e ilahi." **what a blatant lie it is**

Comment: @TheDestroyer I hope you dont mean destroyer of Truth by your name., :)

Comment: Are you blind? I mentioned Shiva Purana Chapter. I am actually replying you without any rants. So, what do you want me to believe? Vedas mentioned God is one. Rig Veda (1.164.46) - "Ekam Sat Vipra Bahudha Vadanti" - Truth is One, men call It by various names.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Here you go., start abuse when cant explain.

Comment: The Destroyer means Lord Shiva. Lord Shiva destroys this world when world is filled with TAMAS. Tamas is all negative traits. So, Shiva actually destroys ignorance, lust and all such negative traits. My name indicates Lord Shiva and not destruction of Truth as you think.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I dont want your own philosophy, I am asking for some proof from your own scriptures for the claims you are making like God created different Devatas from each other during different Kalpas... Please provide if you have or admit its your explanation. Dont abuse, I will stop interaction if you do so.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks for clarifying your name.

Comment: I don't want to abuse you or censure you and sorry if i offend you. Well, as a devout Muslim you reject the notion of Mecca being Shiva Temple but some Hindus believe it as Shiva Temple build by King Vikramaditya. I mentioned you Shiva Puranam chapter which says Supreme Lord created others in all Kalpas. Unfortunately some of our scriptures sucj as Bhavishya Purana were corrupted by Persian invaders and Britishers.  When Smritis (Puranas) contradict Shruti (Vedas), Shruti should be followed.

Comment: Ultimately, Hindus believe Vedas as Truth. Actually, we need to study these scriptures in Sanskrit to understand succinct and subtle meaning of scriptures. Most of these English Translations are done by English men who didn't know proper or allegorical meaning of Sanskrit. So, some misinterpretations exist such as caste system where it was based only on Guna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer -  Not as a devout Muslim, the claim of Shiva temple in mecca is a fallacy being spread by hindus, this should not be done as we should uphold and propagate Truth only. Anyway, thats a whole different thread again, we will discuss it in some other place.

Comment: I studied Vedas in telugu, translated by Dasaradhi Rangacharya, his works are considered as most authentic in that language, he translated them not from english but from Sanskrit. In these vedas I find hundreds of verses for Indra, Agni, varuna etc.,  there are very few hymns for Vishnu and Shiva (rudra).. Only in Puranas I find Vishnu and rudra in more detail and portrayed as superior to other prominent Vedic devatas..  Any explanation for this from your side?

Comment: Being a devotee of Shiva, i will be more delighted if Allah in reality is Shiva. Because we are worshipping same God. Indeed, i personally believe we 7 billion people are worshipping the one same God. This dualities exist just to work in karma. We should have reason to fight and this is only possible when we have some reason (thus making Karma possible.) So, Hindu Philosophy says we should forget all dualities and treat others as equal with no differences. Indeed Advaita says, non-duality. Where when we realize our Atma, we get rid of illusion (MAYA) and we are Brahman.

Comment: Actually Shruti (which are recounted in poetic verses) must be learned from knowledgeable sages. Vedas are Shruti and highest truth. Only a sage can tell you real meaning. I'm not terming Dasaradhi Rangacharya garu as low but we can't just get true meanings of Vedas just by reading them in translations. We must read them in Sanskrit.

Comment: Even i'm a Telugu and want to learn Sanskrit first and then try to learn them from a Guru. Trimurti are given exalted position in Puranas.Unfortunately, some Smriti (which is written) such as Puranas are subjected to interpolations and misinterpretations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38559/discussion-on-answer-by-abdurrahman-why-india-is-only-country-favouring-hinduism).

Comment: @TruthSeeker9 you talk like an atheist also you have not read the Vedas yourself, the main two hymns of vedas narayana suktam and shata rudriyam are for Lord Vishnu and Lord shiva directly.

Answer (score -1):

Who told you. Travel the world my dear. All the religion have only root is Sanatan Dharma. Yes there is declination takes in sanatan dhrma.
I research more then 5 religions (Christianity, Islam, Buddhism etc) and in conclusion they follow some shocking vedic rules.

It is only difference in name due to local language. *They all are equal really*.

like you call tiger I call शेर.