# How did ancient Hindus view other religion's god?

Tags: history

Greeks 'equated' other religion's gods to their gods. We can find it in Herodotus and Plutarch...etc (e.g. Amun=Zeus, Osiris=Dionysus)

Is there any historical records that shows about ancient Hindus' viewpoint to other religion's gods?

**Did they equate other religion's gods to their gods, just like Greek did?** Or, did they incorporate other religion's gods into Hinduism while considering they are not same deity? Or, did they not mention about other religion's god because they thought it is irrelevant?

(P.s. I am not sure from when to when is 'ancient'. Maybe ~500C.E?)

Comment: Abrahamic religions  epistemological , ontological standpoint, vary from Dharmic religions...for an eg.. In vedic view, sound(vibration) is fundamental to other aspects of creation, unlike theirs that God created light first. They say God is seperate from universe in contrast to vedic view God is immanent as well. cyclic nature is not acceptable to them etc. Here God Brahma is a post and not an identity.Religion / symbolism is grounded on philosophy. A metaphysical idea underlies an allegory.Symbolism has a deeper meaning in the light of philosophy.

Comment: By drawing parallels on surface level one may mess up the quintessential phenomenon underlying the same.

Comment: In vedic view, other religions did not exist. There was only Sanatana Dharma :)

Comment: @Athrey The Greek, Egyptian, Persian and Roman religions are not Abrahamic religions.

Comment: True. But Iamn't conversant  with Greek  Philosophy etc , so as to point out how they may differ in essence with Vedic vision.. Comparison with Abrahamic model  is just an eg. to get the point across, that a surface comparison of an allegory or symbolism may not be equitable at all (excepting if it were to be the words of seers). That is why ,only Vedic deities are worshipped...Also  the symbolism of idols(murthis) are strictly according to how it is proposed by Rishis like Markandeya, as the symbolism etc has inconnectedness  with the other components of the Vedic structure , @AravindSuresh

Answer (score 3):

We consider them as false Gods

> या वेदबाह्याः स्मृतयो याश्च काश्च कुदृष्टयः ।
>
> सर्वास्ता निष्फलाः प्रेत्य तमोनिष्ठा हि ताः स्मृताः ॥ ९५ ॥
>
> उत्पद्यन्ते च्यवन्ते च यान्यतोऽन्यानि कानि चित् ।
>
> तान्यर्वाक्कालिकतया निष्फलान्यनृतानि च ॥ ९६ ॥
>
> Those ‘revealed texts’ that are outside the Veda, as also all the
> false theories, are useless, even when carried to perfection; as they
> have been declared to be founded on ‘darkness.’—(95)
>
> Those other (doctrines) which spring up and perish are all worthless
> and false, being of modern growth.—(96)
>
> Manusmriti chapter 12

If you give allegation that we copied vedic hymns and Gods  from other mythologies then also you are wrong

This has already been answered [Source](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/are-there-any-strong-evidence-that-hinduism-religion-is-an-ancient-one)